# Derivative of a integral with independent variable on both the limits and integral infinitesimal

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

In the Mathematics for Machine Learning book, I encountered a derivation that I don't understand. As shown in the picture attached below, I do not understand the reasoning from (6.141) to (6.142). How to do this derivative when $y$ is on both the upper bound and the infinitesimal $dy$?

I understand the derivation that I wrote on the left side using the antiderivative of $f_X(x)$ and the chain rule. So that we can get $f_Y(y)$ directly from (6.139). But I don't understand the book's reasoning of "$f_X(U^{-1}(y))$ is a function of $x$ and not $y$". How can it be a function of $x$ if $x=U^{-1}(y)$ is already substituted into the function $f_X(x)$?

Thank you so much for your help!

[Derivation in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmEkL.jpg)

Comment: Please, make this self-contained, copy the relevant equations instead of linking. Yes, I understand lazyness, but then, potential answerers might be lazy, too. Your decision!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I modified my description and post a more detailed question about my problem.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4492057/derivative-of-a-integral-with-independent-variable-on-both-the-limits-and-integr